# How do I figure out where a kitchen leak is coming from?

Tags: water, kitchens, leak

I have a leak in my kitchen that rears its ugly head whenever there is severe rain and wind. To the best of my knowledge, it has only happened twice. Obviously, I would like to fix this. In the process, it's breaking down some of the drywall.

This is what the damage looks like

[image]

My question is, how do I begin to find where the leak is occurring before I fix the drywall? If I need to hire a contractor, what specifically am I looking for?

Also, does the presence of a patch indicate that the drywall has been fixed before?

Comment: If it's a shingled roof, it's probably blowing under some shingles.  That usually makes a straight-down drip from the entry point.  Have you been above it, like in the attic space?  You can usually spot it pretty easily.

Comment: I have been above it (it's my walk-in closet) and the attic. I can't see any water stains. My initial hunch was that the water was coming from the siding.

Comment: Could be right.  Wouldn't be the first time a leak ran horizontally.  Guess it must be if a closet sits above it.  Given that damage, I'd be ripping it out to find the track.  Gotta fix it anyhow.  And my opinion is that the patch did indicate you're not the first to see a leak.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what my first steps are? I'm not sure how to rip out the broken part before patching it as it looks like a large part of the corner will need to be cared for. Can you recommend something?